# Optimization with coding

Tags: c

I have a program for prime numbers but I need to optimize it. Any hints?

```
  int num, i, count = 0;

  printf("Type a non-negative integer:\n");

 scanf("%d", &num);

  if((num%2 == 0 )&& (num != 2)||(num == 1)){

    printf("%d is not a prime number.\n", num);

  } else if(num == 2){

    printf("%d is a prime number.\n", num);

  } else {

    for(i = 3; i < num; i += 2){

      if(num%i == 0){

    count++;

    break;

      }

    }

    if(count == 0){

      printf("%d is a prime number.\n", num);

    } else {

      printf("%d is not a prime number.\n", num);

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: This may better be asked on [codereview.se]. Stack Overflow specializes in not working code. (Other than you did when registering here, I'd strongly advise to read their [tour](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour).)

Comment: Is it "prime searching" seaons again? Wow, howquichly time goes by ...

Comment: This not a *program*.  Post a complete example and please learn to indent your code with spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to check up to the square root of num.  See [testing primes](http://www.counton.org/explorer/primes/checking-if-a-number-is-prime/) for some more hints.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is one of the basic problems that you might solve it yourself!
I can help you to solve this problem; first start with having a look to the prime numbers definition:

> A prime number is a number that is only diviible by 1 and itself.
>   Assume that we name it **N** then **N** is only divisible by 1 and **N**, and the number 1 is not prime.

So the idea is:

1 - if number is 1 is not prime !

2 - if number is 2 is prime

3 - else ----> we initialize i = 2 , then start calculating the value of **N**%i; if it is 0 the number is not prime, otherwise we must increment i by 1.

We do step 3 until i<**N** (or i<=sqrt(**N**) )

If the number is not divisible by any `i`, then it is prime!

Here is a simple implementation:

```
int n ;
printf("enter n:");
scanf("%d",&n);
if(n<=1) printf("is not prime");
else if(n==2) printf("is prime");
else{
   bool flag = true;
   for(int i = 2 ; i < n ; i++)
      if( n%i==0 ){
         flag = false;
         break;
      }
   if(flag) printf("is prime");
   else printf("is not prime");
}
```

There is a better algorithm to find a series of prime numbers; I think it's better to learn it:

[Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

I hope this tutorial helps you to find out what is a prime number.

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:c] and not [tag:c++].  You can recast your answer as straight C code without much difficulty — and you should.   Providing a C++ answer to a C question is not a good idea.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Oops ! last night i was tired and i saw it c++ :)))
i'll write it in c , thanks for your edit and advice (Y)